# What is the /FD option to cl.exe

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, cl.exe

When I use Visual Studio for a C++ application, it generates a cl.exe command line with an `/FD` option.

But I can't find that option in [the compiler documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s7c9wdw.aspx)

Is it a legacy option?  what does it do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ce2bkt7.aspx).  It's an IDE minimal rebuild and is not exposed to users except through the property page, which is what you're seeing.

Comment: @Ganesh R.:  I had to do a double-take myself.